# i have an array of objects that i can console.log all together but when i want to access a specific element returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello coding a store in javascript vanilla for a assignment. im making a simple ecommerce and i create two classes (Product and ClassListProducts ) and then i consume an api. with  this api i create a class product and push it to the array of ClassListProducts. i cant loop the array neither. My question is why i cant access an specific element inside the array, it returns undefined.

```
class Product {
  constructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
class ClassListProducts {
  constructor() {
    this.lista = [];
    this.addProduct.bind();
  }

  addProduct(id, name) {
    let producto = new Product(id, name);
    this.lista.push(producto);
  }
}
const listProducts = new ClassListProducts();

fetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((json) =>
    json.forEach(({ title, id }) => {
        listProducts.addProduct(id, title);
    })
  );

console.log(listProducts.lista);
console.log(listProducts.lista[0]);
```

[screenshot of the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6o8N.jpg)

sorry for my english.

i tried to use an api and save the products in an object and the save them in array. i want to access specifics element.

Comment: Only access `listProducts` inside the `.then` callback. You're trying to access the first element before the `fetch` finishes.

Comment: In case you're not sure how to implement what @Unmitigated said - just add another `.then(...)` at the very end, and move your `console.log(...)` there (as well as any other logic which relies on `listProducts`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, a network request such as fetch or get isn't instant and takes time to complete.
It returns a promise (look up async in js on YouTube for a good short explanation).

This means you're trying to print the value of something that may not be populated yet. The print statement happens right away while the network request can take longer.

So yeah, moving the print function inside of the .then() method is one way to fix that.

Comment: so how can i do that when the fetch finishes and populate the listProducts.lista all the other logic can use that object list already filled with products, or i have to make fetch and make all the logic inside a .then?

Comment: @matiasposes     For starters, move the two bottom print statements up inside the .then callback after the foreach statement.